# Construct an orthogonal matrix $Q$ satisfying the following formula.

Tags: matrix-decomposition

Suppose $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $D = \operatorname{diag}(d_1,...,d_n) \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}.$ Show how to construct an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that: 
$$
Q^TA-DQ^T=R 
$$
is an upper triangular matrix. Do not worry about the efficiency.

Comment: This is the raw text of your homework, without anything personal. Convince us that you have worked on it...

Comment: You should answer to the questions we ask; This site is based on dialog.

Comment: Sorry to be late. I have tried but cannot find any useful method.